# videoDisplay metadatareceiced ready totaltime

Tags: apache-flex, video, metadata

I'm building a video player that run's FLVs and cannot overcome the fact that flex foes not fire the `metadataReceived` event sometimes. Sometimes it does and sometimes it does not.
therefore the total time of the FLV remains -1.

I understand its a known bug , I'm researching about it for a long time now , but could not find a good workaround by now, found one that says to set the buffer time to 0 and try that, but it's also does not work.

Does anyone has a good workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

What is your `bufferTime` property set to when you initialize the player?  Try setting it to 0?

Comment: same problem to me . So i set bufferTime is 0 to video  but shows same erros(-1) . any other soluation